# Install Canon printer in CUPS on RPI3

Tags: pi-3, cups

I'm trying to install a `Canon MF4570dw` in `CUPS` on a `Raspberry Pi 3`, but I can't make it work.
This is what I've tried so far:

**1. Install the printer from PPD files**

I've extracted the latest Canon driver for my printer `linux-UFRII-drv-v520-usen-05.tar.gz`
I've extracted \linux-UFRII-drv-v520-usen\Sources\cnrdrvcups-lb-5.20-1.tar.gz and took this 2 PPD files: `CNRCUPSMF4500WZS.ppd` and `CNRCUPSMF4500ZS.ppd`
In CUPS admin page I see the printer
[image]
, but on the next screen the printer is not in the list of supported printers so I need to provide a PPD file.
I've tried both of the above files, but when I try to print a test page, nothing is printing.
The printer status seems to be always idle in CUPS.

**2. Install the printer drivers**

Extracting the same driver from above I got this \linux-UFRII-drv-v520-usen\32-bit_Driver\Debian\cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.20-1_i386.deb Debian 32 bit driver.
I've tried to install it, but it's companying about `libcups2` and `libcupsys2`

```sh
sudo apt install ./cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.20-1_i386.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us:i386' instead of './cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.20-1_i386.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 but it is not installable or
                                    libcupsys2:i386 (>= 1.2.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1288845/498148) to enable the i386 packages installation, but I still get `has no installation candidate`

```sh
sudo apt install libcups2:i386 libcupsys2:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libcups2:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libcups2:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libcupsys2:i386
```

Installing the dev version of this packages, `libcups2-dev` and `libcupsys2-dev` still dont allow me to install the above driver and I still get the same reason.

**3. Installing cups-bjnp-2.0.tar.gz**

I've followed [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10012/48173) and extracted cups-bjnp-2.0.tar.gz, than run the config and make commands, but they don't seem to work under the current Raspbian OS

```sh
    $ ./configure –prefix=/usr
    configure: error: invalid variable name: `–prefix'
    $ make
    make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
    $ sudo make install
    make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

**3.1. LATER EDIT**

As suggested by @tttapa the correct configure command is `./configure --prefix=/usr`
After this I got a make error

```sh
bjnp-commands.c: In function ‘bjnp_set_command_header’:
bjnp-commands.c:40:5: error: ‘strncpy’ output truncated before terminating nul copying 4 bytes from a string of the same length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
     strncpy(cmd->header.BJNP_id, BJNP_STRING, sizeof(cmd->header.BJNP_id));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've solved this, by editing the `bjnp-commands.c` file and replacing the `strncpy` by `memcpy` at line 40 as described in [this solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-build-cups-bjnp-2-0-1-a-4175652442/#post5986972)
Then all went well and I was able to add the printer in CUPS admin page with bjnp://:9100, but I'm still asked to chose the printer from the list, and I can't find any MF4500 or MF4570 printer
[image]

**4. Open Printing database**
Searching the [open printing database](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-imageclass_mf4570dn) shows this printer is not yet supported.

**5. Use the new Linux ARM driver**

**5.1 Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit March 4th 2021 release**

When I run the `./install.sh` it fails with this error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./MIPS64/Debian/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_mips64el.deb
 ./ARM64/Debian/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb
 ./x64/Debian/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_amd64.deb
 ./x86/Debian/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_i386.deb
```

Using the Pi OS Printer Settings, I can't find this printer.
From the above message, I conclude it would only work on an 64 bit OS and not on 32 bit.
If I try to install `cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb` I get architecture does not match

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/linux-UFRII-drv-v530-usen/ARM64/Debian $ sudo dpkg -i cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb 
dpkg: error processing archive cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (arm64) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb
```

**5.2 Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit beta April 9th 2021 release (WORKING)**

Install `cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/linux-UFRII-drv-v530-usen/ARM64/Debian $ sudo dpkg -i cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us.
(Reading database ... 89335 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.30-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us (5.30-1) ...
Setting up cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us (5.30-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.31.4-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Printing the test page takes about 6 seconds from when I press print until the page is printed.
Printing a 2 page google search result takes about 20 seconds.

Comment: i386 is the 32-bit x86 architecture (Intel), you cannot use these binaries on an ARM system like the RPi (at least not without emulation). The error in the command in your third section is `–prefix`, it should be two short dashes, not a single hyphen: `--prefix` (As a side note, manually installing stuff in `/usr` is usually a bad idea, it's for software installed by the package manager, manually installed software goes in `/usr/local` or elsewhere.)

Comment: Thanks @tttapa
- changing –prefix for --prefix worked  
- I'm not sure how to emulate x86 drivers on ARM, I'm currently reading about this
- thanks for the installation path recommandation, this is just for testing, at the end I plan on having a clean docker image made for this

Comment: I am trying to do the same, have you had any luck? Mines is MF4580 (MF4500 Series). Like you found, I found a matching PPDs in the `Sources/cnrdrvcups-lb-5.30/ppd/` With ubuntu 20 on an Intel laptop, I can install the `cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.30-1_i386.deb` and get it to print fine, I'm using a RPI2, latest Raspbian.

Comment: I'm trying to diagnose by running `dpkg-deb -c cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.30-1_amd64.deb`. Adding the PPD to `/usr/share/cups/model/` will make it available in the cups printer list

Comment: @Ionut As you have a RPI3, have you tried to install the RPiOS ARM64 variant and then try `dpkg -i cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.30-1_arm64.deb` ? I'm keen to know the results

Comment: @user424174  just noticed Canon has added 2 more Linux drivers, Linux ARM and Linux MIPS
I've installed the rpiOS 64bit beta on rpi3 and executed the install.sh from the the canon ARM driver
than I opened the OS Printer Settings and was able to add MF4500 wireless and able to print a test page

Comment: @Ionut excellent news! Does it render quick? How long does it take for you from the moment you press print (for example a Google results page), for the Canon printer to start? I'm running a RPI2, which means I got it running using i386 emulation, but it takes 2 minutes to render before print begins. So pleased to hear you got it working!

Comment: @user424174 Can you please provide the steps to emulate the i386 architecture and how to installa the driver? I would also like to test this as I have not managed to do it so far

Comment: If you got it working with PI3 and RPIOS ARM64, personally I wouldn't bother with i386, it would be unnecessary overhead. I had no choice because PI2 is 32-bit only. But if you need to I followed this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211022/how-to-install-i386-amd64-packages-on-arm-or-any-other-arch-from-ubuntu-ports/1288845

Comment: Just FYI, you can most likely improve printing speed by switching to Poppler (`pdftops`) from GhostScript: `lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops`

Comment: Also, while MF4570dw native language is UFRII, this printer also supports PCL5/6: https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-imageRunner_4570